# Packrat parsing HTTP

Tags: http, parsing, scala, scala-2.8, parser-combinators

could somebody give me a start on how to parse the HTTP-protocol with scala 2.8 packrat-parsing?

I need to parse attached examplary HTTP Response into

- ResponseStatusCode:Int
- Headers:List[(String,String)]
- Body: String, Array[Byte], CharBuffer
  or whatever

Short examplary usage of a Packrat-Parser very much appreciated. Thanks!

```
HTTP/1.1·200·OK(CR)(LF)
Date:·Thu,·27·May·2010·12:18:48·GMT(CR)(LF)
Server:·Apache(CR)(LF)
Vary:·Accept-Encoding,User-Agent(CR)(LF)
Connection:·close(CR)(LF)
Transfer-Encoding:·chunked(CR)(LF)
Content-Type:·text/html;·charset=utf-8(CR)(LF)
(CR)(LF)
... Hello World ..
```

Comment: I think using a combinator parser for this is using a sledgehammer to kill a flea. Well, maybe a sledgehammer to kill a cockroach. Note, too, that the packrat part is about making the parser more efficient when it backtracks. Offhand, I don't see the decoding of HTTP responses as needing any backtracking, so the packrat aspect is moot.

Comment: OK but what be an elegant yet efficient solution to parse arbitrary standard-compliant http-responses?

Comment: Is your interest in the experience of writing a decoder for HTTP responses? Or do you just want to consume them? If it's the latter, I would just use one of the off-the-shelf libraries. Apache HttpComponents (http://hc.apache.org/) would be the obvious suggestion.

Comment: I need a custom and efficient HTTP-Parser for handling NIO data-chunks in a CPS-Context. My working draft is at: http://github.com/hotzen/Thesis/tree/master/src/dataflow/io/http/ I'm sorry for commenting late. Appreciate any advice on how to properly design such a parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are abundant [on-line resources about using Scala's combinator parser library](http://www.google.com/search?q=Scala+Combinator+Parser).

Comment: I thought there were bigger differences between "old-school" parsers and the new packrat parsers.

Comment: @hotzen: The Scala 2.8 combinator parser library adds PEG parsing and can memoize parse results for potential re-use when backtracking occurs. I don't see either of these as being pertinent to parsing HTTP responses. Perhaps I'm mistaken.

Comment: You are totally right but as this is a current parsing-job to be done, I thought I could have a look into the packrats...

Comment: @hotzen: I still don't see this as a parsing problem. It's just an matter of decoding an unordered collection of key/value pairs. It can be done with parsing techniques and tools, but I still think that's excessive. And since it's not something you're doing for the sake of writing a parser, you should use an existing library (http://hc.apache.org/).